# How to get table count even when query is limited?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, say im doing a limited query function like this:

```
function getLogList()
{
    $table='logs';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,timestamp,votes FROM {$table} ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1, 20");
    return $result;
}
```

If the table has lets say 460 entries, is there a way I can make my function also return the total count with its return?

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/mysql-get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in conjunction with FOUND_ROWS:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,title,timestamp,votes FROM {$table} ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1, 20;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` right after your query executes.